# How do I use async-await properly in the following situation?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, request-promise

I'm struggling with async await block. I have looked the multiple resources on the net but I just can't understand what I'm doing wrong here :

```
app.post('/api/my-api', async (req, res, next) => {
try {
    filecontent = req.files.userFile.data.toString('utf8')
    console.log("decoded file : ", filecontent);
    let encoded_file = new Buffer(filecontent).toString('base64');
    var apiClass = new RPC("http://localhost:1006", "my-api");

    //the asynchronous function :
    const answ = await apiMethod.call("api", [{"file" : encoded_file, "fileName":req.files.userFile.name}], res.json);

    //the code I'd like to execute only after the previous function has finished :
    console.log("answer : ", answ);
    console.log("answering...");
    res.json(answ);
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
}
```

Apparently my `console.log` are executed before the the `await` line is done. I can tell because there's a `console.log()` in the asynchronous function too, and my `res.json` is sent before I receive `answ`.

How do I make sure the asynchronous function finishes before the rest of the code ?

Edit : here is the apiMethod.call function :

```
call(id, params) {
    let options = {
        url: this.url,
        method: "post",
        headers:
        { 
         "content-type": "text/plain"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify( {"jsonrpc": "2.0", "id": id, "method": this.procedure, "params": params })
    };
    console.log(options);
    request(options, (error, response, body) => {
        if (error) {
            console.error('An error has occurred: ', error);
        } else {
            console.log('Post successful: response: ', body);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Can `app.post` be `await`ed ?

Comment: What does `apiMethod.call` return?

Comment: Looks like that your apiMethod.call does not return a Promise. What is the value of ```answ``` in your ```console.log("answer : ", answ)``` ?

Comment: well, it's answ is "undefined". answ is supposed to be the answer from the call to an API. So if I have to make it return a promise, how do I also get the answer from the API ?

Comment: @anis — We have no idea how `apiMethod` works, so it’s *really* hard to suggest how it could be changed to work differently.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. If `apiMethod.call` doesn't return anything you can't await it. Does it expect a callback? _"So if I have to make it return a promise, how do I also get the answer from the API ?"_ The promise contains the answer.

Comment: I added the .call() function too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is in `call` function. Since it has async code (`request` call), it should be wrapped in promise which should resolve from callback function of `request`.

Updating call function to something like below should help:

```
function call(id, params) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let options = {
      url: this.url,
      method: "post",
      headers: {
        "content-type": "text/plain",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        jsonrpc: "2.0",
        id: id,
        method: this.procedure,
        params: params,
      }),
    };
    console.log(options);
    request(options, (error, response, body) => {
      if (error) {
        console.error("An error has occurred: ", error);
        reject(error);
      } else {
        console.log("Post successful: response: ", body);
        resolve(body);
      }
    });
  })
}
```